# Export the settings of the Internet Explorer to a textfile

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

Is there a MS tool for exporting the settings of the internet explorer to a textfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how:

- Click on Start -> Run
- Type gpedit.msc
- Navigate to Local computer policy ->
  Computer Configuration ->
  Administrative Templates -> Windows
  Components -> Internet Explorer
- Right click on Internet Explorer and
  you can Export all the settings.